How do Bible scholars explain the term " Come to the Father" in Jn 14:6?
We hear Jesus saying in Jn 14:3-6( NKJV):

And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come again and receive you to Myself; that where I am, there you may be also.  And where I go you know, and the way you know.”
Thomas said to Him, “Lord, we do not know where You are going, and how can we know the way?” .Jesus said to him, “I am the way, the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through Me.

Here, Jesus starts with saying that he is GOING to the Father, but ends with  stating  that no one COMES to the Father except through him.
In first appearance Jesus is defying the rules of  language that govern distance and time. For instance, a person residing in New York says: "My children  will come home tomorrow and together we will go to Washington to see my parents" .But in case he is presently in Washington, he might as well say:" I will pick up my children from New York  and   all of us  will  come to see my parents in Washington".
If Jesus said " Come to the Father" he said so with a specific purpose. How do Bible scholars explain it ?

I do not understand your question. In Spirit, one has a relationship with the Father and the Son. This is not a matter of coming or going physically. Also, on this site it is we, ourselves, who analyse text using hermeneutics rather than consulting 'scholars'. Perhaps this should be asked on SE-C.

@Kadalikatt Joseph Sibichan I do not understand the focus of your question. e.g., you say "If Jesus said" but the ESV says "Jesus said". Why do you put "if"? Also you say "come" [like an order] but your Bible quote says "comes" to the Father.

C.Stroud, please see the illustration of the New Yorker given in my question. You will understand the nuance.

Actually, the situation with the verbs in the Greek of John 14:1-6 is not as simple and distinct as most English versions suggest.  Let me be specific.  In English, just two verbs of displacement are used: "to come" and "to go".  The Greek has the following:

ἔρχομαι (erchomai), V6, can be translated as either "to come" or "to go" but mostly the former
πορεύομαι (poreuomai), V2, V3, means to travel, journey, go or die, etc.
ὑπάγω (hupago), V5, to go away, depart, die, etc.

Thus, the distinction between "going" and "coming" is not a stark and simple as it first appears.
In any case, no one is literally going to the Father because these words in V5, & V6 are intended in a metaphorical sense of coming to the Father in a spiritual sense.  Jesus said this earlier when he stated:

John 12:32 - And I, when I am lifted up from the earth, will draw
everyone to Myself."

Thus, Jesus, and our faith in His merits and sacrifice, is the only way to come to the Father and have eternal life.  Jesus taught Nicodemus the same thing in John 3.

Thanks, Dottard. If the word Jesus originally used had two different sets of meaning, the translators would differ in their rendering. The fact is that all translations except a few like GW use the word 'comes '.

What Jesus said in John 14:6 has to stand in relation to what he had previously said. In John 5:40 he had said, "And you will not come to me, that you might have life." Now, Jesus is not the Father. Bear that in mind. Then, in John chapter 6 he made other related statements. At first reading, there may appear to be a similar puzzle to resolve as in chapter 14, but when all those statements of Jesus are put together, the answer to this question should become clear. I'm going to extract the related verses, and list them below, starting with chapter 6.

"Jesus answered and said unto them, This is the work of God, that ye
believe on him whom he hath sent. (v. 29)


...and him that cometh to me I will in no wise cast out. (v. 37)


No man can come to me, except the Father which hath sent me draw him; (v. 44)


And he said, Therefore
said I unto you, that no man can come unto me, except it were given
unto him of my Father. (v. 65) All quotes from chapter 6 as in the
A.V.

Notice what is said about 'coming'. The question is about 'coming' and also about 'going'. Coming and going. The verses quoted give the order of those events.
First, Jesus was sent by the Father, to come into the world, as the light of the world, to enable the way to the Father to be seen. He said that those who wanted to draw close to the Father had to come to him, as the Son of God. We have to come to Jesus, in believing faith. Everybody that comes to Jesus shall not be cast out, but 'received'.
Ah, but in order for us to come to Jesus, the Father must enable that 'coming'! The Father draws people to the Son, that they might have life.
This is where the text in question now slots in. Jesus will go to the Father in heaven, but will come again for those who belong to him by faith. Then they will be taken to be with both the Father and the Son. The way to the Father, Jesus reminds Philip, is that no-one comes to the Father except by himself.
Language about distance and time will hardly help us to appreciate the spiritual matters Jesus is explaining. Yet he uses plain words to make us think about astounding, invisible and spiritual truths. He speaks about coming and going - then coming back again so that those who have (spiritually) come to the Father through Christ will eventually be in heaven, with the Father and the Son.
For now, before Christ returns, he promises the comforting indwelling of the Holy Spirit, plus this beauty:

"...he that loveth me shall be loved of my Father, and I will love
him, and will manifest myself to him...  If a man love me, he will
keep my words: and my Father will love him, and we will come unto him,
and make our abode with him. John 14:21 & 23 K.J.V.

This abiding in Christ (see chapter 15:1-8) results in both Christ and the Father abiding in that believer, by the Spirit. This is before Jesus comes again to receive his own unto himself, to take them to heaven.
There's a lot of coming and going going on here, and not all of it is literal, for the gap between heaven and earth, and the span between time and eternity requires a deeper understanding than our limited grasp of earthly time and distance.

Thanks, Anne. Jesus did place eternal truth above mundane grammar . " Before Abraham was, I am " (Jn 8:58).
